# jquery scrollTo: TypeError undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of horizontally stacked divs, with ids `pageContent1`, `pageContent2` and so on. I want to scroll to the next page on the right when the right arrow key is pressed, and to the previous page on the left when the left key is pressed. I'm using jquery's scrollTo method (http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/). Here's the code:

```
var
    hp_first = 1,
    hp_last = $('.page').length,
    hp_curr = 1

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: //left
            if(window.hp_curr > window.hp_first) {
                $('body').scrollTo('#pageContainer' + --window.hp_curr)
            }
            break

        case 39: //right
            if(window.hp_curr < window.hp_last) {
                $('body').scrollTo('#pageContainer' + ++window.hp_curr)
            }
            break

        default: return
    }
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

This gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function VM1698:17(anonymous function) VM1698:17jQuery.event.dispatch notable-bootstrap.js:4676elemData.handle notable-bootstrap.js:4360
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of jquery is on your page?

Comment: It's not working because `hp_first = hp_curr = 1`
So the code within the if statement can't be executed in both cases.

Comment: @WissamEl-Kik why would it not satisfy the second if condition? The total number of pages is more than 1

Comment: also, if it didn't satisfy the if condition, it wouldn't have the error from the scrollTo call, which is inside the if condition.

Comment: Maybe ... I don't have the HTML code.
As far as I know, the error you provided isn't related to the ScrollTo plugin. It's clearly marked that it's a Bootstrap.js error.

Comment: I haven't added any html, just modifying javascript on the page